# Python OOP name error: "lib_list" not defined despite being there

Tags: python, object, oop

im trying to initialize a list object with various items found in a text file. However, whenever I call the argument, it says name "lib_list" is not defined, even though it is. I also tried calling catalog without the argument, but then it says a positional argument, "lib_list", required. I'm just not sure what to do and would greatly appreciate some insight

```
class InvalidItem(Exception):
    #your code here
    def __init__(self, error):
        self.error

#defing InvalidOption Exception class
class InvalidOption(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error):
        self.error

#define a Catalog class and a serach method
class Catalog:
    def __init__(self, lib_list: list):
        self.lib_list = lib_list
    
    def search(self, lib_type, lib_title):
        for item in self.lib_list:
            if type(item) == lib_type and item.Title == lib_title:
                return item
        return None

#define a LibraryItem class
class Library_Item:
    def __init__(self, genre, author, stack_num):
        self.genre = genre
        self.author = author
        self.stacknum = stack_num

#define a Book, Magazine class
class Book(Library_Item):
    def __init__(self, title, genre, stack_num, isbn, author):
        super().__init__(title, genre, stack_num)
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.author = author
    def __str__(self):
        listing = (f'{self.title}' \
                 f'{self.author}' \
                 f'{self.isbn}' \
                 f'{self.stack_num}')
        return listing
class Magazine(Library_Item):
    def __init__(self, title, genre, stack_num, volume_num, issue):
        super().__init__(title, genre, stack_num)
        self.volume_num = volume_num
        self.issue = issue
    def __str__(self):
        listing = (f'{self.title}' \
                 f'{self.volume_num}' \
                 f'{self.issue}' \
                 f'{self.stack_num}')
        return listing

#define a main function -----
def main():
    file_name = 'D:\\Users\Owner\\Desktop\\library.txt'
    lib_items = []
    print("-----------------------")
    print("Welcome to library menu")
    print("-----------------------")
    #read file information and create book/magazine object
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            listings = line.strip().split(',')
            item_type = listings[0]
            title = listings[1]
            genre = listings[2]
            stack_num = listings[3]

            #find the item type
            if item_type == 'book':
                #create a book object
                isbn = listings[4]
                author = listings[5]
                book1 = Book(title,genre,stack_num,isbn,author)
                listings.append(book1)
            else:
                volume_num = listings[4]
                issue = listings[5]
                mag1 = Magazine(title, genre, stack_num, isbn, issue)
                listings.append(mag1)

    LibCat = Catalog(lib_list)
    print('Library Database loaded')

    x = 1
    while x ==1:
        try:
            choice = int(input("\n1. Search \n2. Exit \n Enter choice (1-2): "))
            if choice != 1 and choice != 2:
                raise InvalidOption("Invalid option. Returning to main menu")
        except InvalidOption as invalid:
            print(invalid.error)
            continue

        if choice == 1:
            item_type = input("Please enter the item type (book/magazine): ")
            item_title = input("Please enter the item title: ")

            if item_type == "book":
                item_type = Book
            elif item_type == "magazine":
                item_type = Magazine
            else:
                item_type = None

            try:
                search = LibCat.search(item_type, item_title)
                if not search:
                    raise InvalidItem("Sorry, this itme is not valid")
                else:
                    print("-----Item Information-----")    
                    print(search)
            except InvalidItem as item:
                print(item.error)
                continue
        else:
            print("Exiting database")
            break

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send `lib_list` in the class `Catalog`. The problem here is, in your `main()` function you have nowhere defined `lib_list` and `lib_list` is a parameter name for the `Catalog __init__()` it is not a pre-defined variable. To fix this error:

```
# Change line 82:
LibCat = Catalog(listings) # Assuming listings is your variable related with "lib_list"
```

You simply need to put the variable that you want the class to take as `lib_list` rather than putting `lib_list` itself.